# Why int is narrowed to float?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-narrowing

Given an example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(float) {}

int main()
{
    int i{43};
    foo(float{i});

    return 0;
}
```

Compilers (clang, msvc) does not compile this (GCC compiles, but with warning): `non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from 'int' to 'float' in initializer list`.

Why compilers say that `int` is *narrowed* to `float` when `float` is *wider* than `int`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because of the *precision* of the float, which is only 7-digit, despite it has *larger* range than int.

So if you try to represent int number with more than 7-digit precision to float you *might* likely get some loss. - in this sense it is called *narrowed*. Though float has *wider* range than int, it has *less* precision.

Besides, floating point representation is *approximation* - that is, it does not represent *exact* number (except for power of 2). In that sense, the int is also narrowed.

Comment: You'd get the same error if you converted to `double`, despite `double` having higher precision than `int` on common implementations.

Comment: Because of the imprecision nature of the floating point, you say?

Comment: On any platforms you're likely to be using, `double` can precisely represent every `int` value (not as an approximation, but as an accurate value). But the standard still calls this narrowing because it doesn't know what platform you're running this on. See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: I accept the premise, but I'm curious, are there any platforms that do this? I'm having trouble with my search terms...